# "Cannot populate JSON array for type" When trying insert data

Tags: json, azure, xamarin, mobileserviceclient

Update: After all day messing with this, I fixed it. 
I Changed my `mobileserviceclient` URL to include https instead of HTTP. 
I think this was causing my post to instead be a get request that returned an array of "Comment" and tried to parse it to a single "Comment" therefore the error.

Having trouble debugging this, I have the following table/class:

```
public class Comment
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string MenuItemId { get; set; }
    }
```

Using `AzureMobileServiceClient` I can get data from the Azure Mobile App into my Xamarin App so the JSON returned from the client must be getting deserialized into my Comment type but when I try to add data using the following code:

```
var comment = new Comment
                {                         
                    Content = NewComment,
                    MenuItemId = Item.Id,
                    UserId = App.CloudService.CurrentUser.UserId
                };

                await App.CloudService.client.GetTable<Comment>().InsertAsync(comment);
```

I get the error "Cannot populate JSON array onto type 'Comment'"

I can insert the data fine using postman definitely something wrong on the client-side. I saw one other question on this and they said they fixed it by deleting the project and remaking but I'd rather figure out what is actually happening.

Comment: Can I vote this up more than once? :)  Turns out if you just copy the App Service Overview page URL, you **don't** get the "HTTPS", just "HTTP".  Oops.